# Simple expression for $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {2n+E-1 \choose 2n} x^{2n}$?

Tags: combinatorics, power-series

The title basically says it all.  If $2n$ was just $n$, I think it's relatively simple:

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {n+E-1 \choose n} x^{n} = \frac{1}{(1-x)^E}$.

But what if you want every other term, i.e.

$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {2n+E-1 \choose 2n} x^{2n}$

Can anyone think of a simple expression for that?

Comment: How about $1/(1-x^2)^E$

Comment: $$\frac{\frac{1}{(1-x)^E}+\frac{1}{(1+x)^E}}{2}$$

Comment: Ah, thank you rumpelstiltskin, I think that must be it!  I'm asleep at the wheel today...

Comment: This is a special case of multisection of series. Look it up.

Answer (score 0):

We have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{n+E-1}{n} x^n =\frac{1}{(1-x)^E}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Break this into its odd & even powers of $x$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n+E-1}{2n} x^{2n} +\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n+E}{2n+1} x^{2n+1} =\frac{1}{(1-x)^E}=\frac{(1+x)^E}{(1-x^2)^E}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now binomially expand the numerator and collect the even powers of $x$ and we have
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n+E-1}{2n} x^{2n} =\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^E} \sum_{i=0}^{ \lfloor \frac{E}{2} \rfloor} \binom{E}{2i} x^{2i}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: It's a nice idea, and based on rumpelstiltskin's answer above, your sum $\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor{E/2}\rfloor}{E \choose 2i}x^{2i}=1/2[(1-x)^E + (1+x)^E]$